# Is ResultSetMetaData ever null?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, nullpointerexception, metadata, resultset

I am using SQL server 2005.

Here is the code

```
private TableObject getTableObject(ResultSet rs, boolean raw) throws TableObjectException
    {
        TableObject to = new TableObject();//In this class all variable is ArrayList type
        if (rs == null)
            return to;
        try
        {
            ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount = rsm.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
            {
                to.setColLabel(rsm.getColumnLabel(i));
                to.setColType(rsm.getColumnClassName(i));
            }
            while (rs.next())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    if (raw)
                    {
                        switch (rsm.getColumnType(i + 1))
                        {
                            case java.sql.Types.DATE:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getDate(i + 1));
                                break;
                            case java.sql.Types.VARCHAR:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getString(i + 1));
                                break;
                            case java.sql.Types.INTEGER:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getInt(i + 1));
                                break;
                            case java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getTimestamp(i + 1));
                                break;
                            case java.sql.Types.TIME:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getTime(i + 1));
                                break;
                            default:
                                to.addColumn(rs.getString(i + 1));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        to.addColumn(rs.getString(i + 1));
                    }
                }
                to.addRow();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
// LINE NO : 289
        throw new TableObjectException("Exception generated while creating TableObject from Resultset :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return to;
    }

}
```

Once, we got the following error where (e.getMessage()) error message is NULL .

```
com.os.exceptions.TableObjectException: Exception generated whicle creating TableObject from Resultset :null
at com.os.db.DbManager.getTableObject(DbManager.java:289)
```

It seems, this error is due to `NPE` but the fact is **Resultset (rs) and ResultSetMetaData (rsm) never null**. So I'm wondring from where we got this error. For safer side we already have check `rs == null` check.

I am unable to reproduce the same error again. But still interested in the root cause. Was it because of null ResultSetMetaData?

Answer (score 1):

A `NullPointerException` in this case could only be caused by a bug in your JDBC driver. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29), only a `SQLException` should be thrown by the call to `getMetaData()`. It would be helpful if you posted the output of a call to `e.printStackTrace()` because it's pretty much impossible to debug an `NPE` on a forum such as this without one. It would also be helpful if you included information about the driver you are using.

Comment: Thanks for respond , i use sqljdbc ,Now unable to reproduce this bug again .Before we haven't use `e.printStackTrace()` that's way its hard to track reason to produce this bug.

Comment: I would guess that getting the source for Microsoft's driver is probably not an option, so your only option, if you get a stack trace again, would be to contact Microsoft support. In terms of exception handling, it's generally a bad idea to just `catch (Exception)` because you also catch `RuntimeException` subclasses, and in this case it caused you to lose important information. Also, your `TableObjectException` class hopefully supports chaining, but you're not using that feature in your sample code either. Chaining is another important tool that keeps you from losing stack traces.